# How to cache a User Control for one day

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, user-controls

I have a user control that draws a table

I have another user control that draws images

I want to cache both the user control for one day , it means for everyday if a user visits table and images will be generated only for first time and saved to cache and used whole day from cache for any subsequent visit.

This cache should be depended on three keys including logged in user key

I have written custom code for images and it is working fine, I am storing these images to a folder. this is without using output caching.

Now I don't have any idea how to store Table to a folder, so I want to implement caching for table using Output Caching of user control.

I don't know how to cache it for one day.

As instructed by Rick I added the following directive to user control

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="None" Shared="true"
    VaryByControl="Key1;Key2;Key3" %>
```

And wrote the following code to consumer page

```
DashboardControl dc = null;
Control control = (Control)Page.LoadControl(urlBuilder.GetCompleteURL().TrimEnd('?'));
  if (control is DashboardControl)
  {
    dc = control as DashboardControl;
  }
  else if (control is PartialCachingControl && ((PartialCachingControl)control).CachedControl != null)
  {
    dc = (DashboardControl)((PartialCachingControl)control).CachedControl;
  }
```

But CachedControl always give null , any idea?

Comment: Please give details about the keys. Are they part of the URL?

Comment: no they are session variables

Comment: Then `@OutputCache` isn't going to work... Stire the data in the Cache object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="None" Shared="true"
      VaryByControl="Key1;Key2;Key3" %>
```

Where Key1, Key2 and Key3 are a properties on the control whose value is used to vary the cache.

When a `Control` is output cached, *only its output is placed in the cache*, not the `Control` itself. On subsequent requests where the output cache is used, references to the `Control` will be null, so you need to set properties on the Control the first time it's referenced.

For a cached `Control`, `LoadControl()` will return a `PartialCachingControl` type, which you can use to add the result to your `Page`. But the `Control` class itself is not there, so you can't use that reference to set property values or invoke methods.

Comment: what does mean by Shared there? will this last if user logs off?

Comment: When I do this I get this error:   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.PartialCachingControl' to type 'Brady.TISCOR.TISCORDirect.WebHelper.DashboardControl'.

Comment: Shared="true" means that the key for the output cache will not include the Type of the Page that contains the control. Otherwise, by default, it will include the Page Type. Yes, (either way) it will last if a user logs off. For the error you're seeing, perhaps you can post some code?

Comment: Thanks Rick, I was trying to load user control using LoadControl and casting it to DashboardChart ( my usercontrol type). I found that this is not possible in case of partial caching , When the user control is from caching it is of type PartialCachingControl. I am modifying the code.

Comment: please see I modified the post

Comment: oh than how can I pass those three keys to the control?

Comment: You set the keys (property values) the first time the Control runs, before it goes into the output cache (either when this.YourControlId != null, or declaratively).

Comment: Do you have to use LoadControl()? Or is a declarative approach OK?

Answer (score 2):

Try using following code example  for  caching user control . Here you have to change the duration as per your requirement and User control name as per your control:

```
    <%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="none" 
    VaryByControl="CategoryDropDownList" %>
```

For more refer link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Comment: Note that this is for 60 _seconds_. And how about UserKey?

Comment: this is not helping me out as it is dependent on CategoryDropDownList , I want it to depend on lets say three Session variables and not 60 seconds it should not update cache untill last cache is updated on same day

Comment: CategoryDropDownList is the name of Control for example. You can give your User Control Id there.

Comment: Refer the link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.cache(v=vs.71).aspx   if it helps.

Comment: thats a simple caching , please reply to message if you know the specific answer

Answer (score 0):

It always gives null if the control (PartialCachingControl) is not added to the page, after you added of some way to the page and render the control, it will give you access via CachedControl property.